# What is the difference between ein Monat, einen Monat, and einem Monat?

Tags: word-usage, difference, grammatical-case, german-to-english

I am confused as to when to use each of the three phrases from the title, especially the “einem Monat”

Would saying “in less than one month” be “Weniger als ein Monat noch“ ?

Thank you!

Comment: Context please? These all are context dependent. We can't give you a general answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Well, the grammatical difference can well be explained, along with a hint that which to use when depends mostly on the vocabulary used in context.

Comment: I would like to say “Less than one month left until Austria” in the sense of, that in less than one month, I will be in Austria.

Comment: This should be covered in any beginner level German book. Depending on the case (Nominativ, Genitiv, Dativ, Akkusativ) you need to use the coresponding form. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Monat#Declension

Comment: I have trouble learning grammar due to a TBI, but I am trying. I understand then  now that in my example it is ein or einen. Because of the weird structure of my sentence, i think Monat is the subject so it will be ein, but I am not sure and that is why I was asking on here

Answer (score 1):

*in less than one month*

> in weniger als ein**em** Monat

That's dative. Why? Because the German preposition *in* requires the dative case when you describe a spot in time. That's all the magic.

Comment: Thank you, Janka for that brilliant tip! If I was to say it as “Less than one month left...”, it would be “Weniger als ein Monat noch” because the month is the subject so it is nominative, right?

Comment: You had no preposition demanding a specific case then. *Weniger als ein Monat bleibt uns noch.* (subject)  or *Sie müssen weniger als einen Monat abwarten.* (accusative object).